# Finding the Size of a Model in Google App Maker

Tags: datasource, google-app-maker

Ive been trying to figure out how Google App Maker works with models by trying to write a simple button to return the length(number of records) that exists within a model I've created and loaded temporary data into (which should have about 150 records).

I'm working with a model called Generic Logs that has ten different

```
app.models.GenericLogs.fields._values.length - Returns 10
alert(app.models.GenericLogs.fields.Id.maxValue) - Returns null 
alert(app.models._values.length) - Returns 2 (I have a second model) 
alert(app.models.GenericLogs.datasources._values.length) - Returns 1
```

I definitely want to get the 150+ response for all of the records (non-unique)

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

Set your datasource limit setting to 0 and do `console.log(app.datasources.YourDatasource.items.length)`. The downside to this is that all records will be returned to the client and might slow down your UI.

Option 2:

Create a server function -

```
function YourFunction() {
  var query = app.models.YourModel.newQuery();
  query.limit = 0;
  var results = query.run();
  return results.length;
}
```

Create a button in your client and attach the following to the onClick event `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (serverresult) {console.log(serverresult)}).YourFunction()`

Reference: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/server#querying_records

Comment: I'll try this out! I was getting close but it was timing out the preview page. I hadn't set the query limit so I'm guessing it was causing that issue.



`function arraylength() {
  var fullgeneric = app.models.GenericLogs.newQuery().run();
  return fullgeneric.length;
}`

Comment: Not necessarily. You don’t really have to set the query limit explicitly in a server script, and it will still return all records.